# SASS nested classes with babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Tags: sass, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I'd like to turn the `<label>` in this div red:

```
<div styleName="foo">
  Some green text
  <label styleName="bar">Bar</label>
</div>
```

My associated SCSS file looks like:

```
.foo {
  color: green;
  .bar {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Is it possible, with `babel-plugin-react-css-modules`, to use this nesting feature of SCSS?